# Run command in open ssh session from external terminal

Tags: linux, ssh

Is it possible to ssh into a remote server, leave it open and then from a separate source on the same local machine, say another terminal or a subprocesses started in python, run a command in the same ssh session? (And of course eventually closing the connection after I am done.)

The remote server in question uses two factor authorization which is fine when opening the connection once but is basically a huge problem when I automatically want to launch additional commands at run-time of a locally run program.

Comment: I think you're looking for `screen` or [`tmux`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) which  you run on the remote server but maybe I misunderstand your question.

Comment: @HermanB, I will have a look, but I think that ControlMaster is what I need:https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218276/288916.